# Copy range to another sheet and insert name from Input Box with this copy

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have User form where I have command button and input text box.

I want to copy specified range from one worksheet, then name and paste in another sheet.
My code looks like this, but it is not working.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim i, LastRow
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim k As Integer
Set ws = Worksheets("Vali")
LastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 4 To LastRow 'find fulfiled rows
If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "D").Value = 1 Then
Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(i, "B"), Cells(i, "D")).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Vali").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
End If
Next i
Dim i As Integer
'Next we use a looping process 'We start the loop from row 2 because our worksheet has headers in row 1
For k = 2 To 100
'Now we define a condition that only if there is data under the headers ItemID, Description,
If Cells(k, "A").Value <> "" And Cells(k, "B").Value <> "" And Cells(k, "C").Value <> "" And Cells(k, "D").Value <> "" And Cells(k, "E").Value = "" Then
Cells(k, "D").Value = Me.txtname.Value
End If
Next
Range("E:E").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Range("B4:D21").ClearContents 'clear content on previos sheet, from where we made copy
ActiveWorkbook.Save
ValiFinish.Hide
End Sub
```

Comment: Plz use the {} icon to rearrange code in a readable way. What does it says when the error prompt? And on which line?

Comment: thank you, I could not  understand, some times it says that invalid use of Me keyword, but sometimes somehow it makes action but no data is entered in E column. also it says about IF without block. I think IF condition is not by deliberate way.  please consider that the command button is on sheet 1.

Comment: The command button is making only copy from one sheet to another, but when I am typing name in inputbox, the name is ot inserted.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you were trying to do with your test on you second loop, because there was no sheet reference, so I choose, let me know if it wasn't that

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim LastRow As Double
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Wv As Worksheet
    Dim k As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim Ti()
    ReDim Ti(0)
    Dim StartPaste As Double
    Dim EndPaste As Double
    Dim PastedRange As String

    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set Wv = Worksheets("Vali")

LastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
StartPaste = Wv.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

For i = 2 To LastRow
    If ws.Cells(i, "D").Value = 1 Then

        ws.Range(ws.Cells(i, "A"), ws.Cells(i, "D")).Copy _
             Destination:=Wv.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        Ti(UBound(Ti)) = i
        ReDim Preserve Ti(UBound(Ti) + i)
        EndPaste = Wv.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row - 1

        '2 options because i'm not sur where you want to add the text :
        'First one (write on Vali, I think that's what you are looking to do) :
        If Wv.Cells(EndPaste, "A").Value <> "" And Wv.Cells(EndPaste, "B").Value <> "" And Wv.Cells(EndPaste, "C").Value <> "" _
           And Wv.Cells(EndPaste, "D").Value <> "" And Wv.Cells(EndPaste, "E").Value = "" Then
               Wv.Cells(Wv.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row, "E").Value = ValiFinish.TxTNaMe.Value
        End If
        'Second one (write on Sheet1) :
        If ws.Cells(i, "A").Value <> "" And ws.Cells(i, "B").Value <> "" And ws.Cells(i, "C").Value <> "" _
           And ws.Cells(i, "D").Value <> "" And ws.Cells(i, "E").Value = "" Then
               ws.Cells(ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row, "E").Value = ValiFinish.TxTNaMe.Value
        End If
        'end of options
    End If
Next i

PastedRange = "" & Wv.Name & "!R" & StartPaste & "C1:R" & EndPaste & "C3"
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=ValiFinish.TxTNaMe.Value, RefersToR1C1:=PastedRange




'clear content on previous sheet, from where we made copy
For i = LBound(Ti) To UBound(Ti) - 1
   ws.Range("$B$" & Ti(i) & ":$D$" & Ti(i)).ClearContents
Next i


    Wv.Range("E:E").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Set ws = Nothing
    Set Wv = Nothing

    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ValiFinish.Hide
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your support, maybe my question was wrongly,
Step 1.
I have user form including command button and input text box.

Step 2.
I have two sheet - Sheet1 and Vali
Step 3.
I want to copy fulfilled range "B:D"  from Sheet1 to Vali.
4 Step.
I want to give name to copied Range on Vali(Sheet).
So, I have copied range where is some data and I want to give name to this range and paste on Vali(sheet)

I have tried this code but it is give me { run time error 424 }

Comment: I edited it, let me know! If it is good plz validate answer to close subject

Comment: On which line?? Give me a maximum details plz

Comment: @DatoPilpilashvili : It works perfectly for me... I just corrected the EndPaste use in PastedRange string to include a "-1"

Comment: So, you mean EndPaste without -1?

it is giving {run time error 424, required object}. I don't know exactly on which line.

Comment: Is it when you click on the button? when you open the UserForm? For EndPaste, the selection was a row too large, so I just added a -1 which wasn't there on the previous edit

Comment: Have you checked if your UserForm is called `ValiFinish`, your TextInput `TxTNaMe` and that you have the 2 sheets `Vali` and `Sheet1`?
I can't see where you can get a required object as it's running for me... Are you in `Option Explicit`?