# How can I name a range ("B1:Bn") using a macro where 'n' may increase in future

Tags: vba, excel

Basically I want to name a Range("B1:Bn") so that I can use that name for a `Combobox` to list the value of that range but here range/list may increase so I want this range to be dyanamic and so shoud have the same name for that range.
I have written a code below:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Dim Total_Row As Integer
    Total_Row = Worksheets("Database").Range("B1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
    Range("B1:B11").Select

    'Now I want something like `Range("B1:B***Total_Row***").Select`
End sub
```

or can we make it dynamic using below code?

```
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="Testing", _
        RefersToR1C1:="=Database!R2C2:R***(Total_Row)***C2"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (don't forget to define the `Worksheet_Name`)

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
Dim Total_Row As Integer
Dim Pasted_Range As String
Total_Row = Worksheets("Database").Range("B1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
Pasted_Range = "=" & Worksheet_Name & "!R2C2:R" & Total_Row & "C2"

ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="Testing", RefersToR1C1:=Pasted_Range
End Sub
```

Check this for more info : [Copy range to another sheet and insert name from Input Box with this copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29413522/copy-range-to-another-sheet-and-insert-name-from-input-box-with-this-copy/29428454#29428454)

Answer (score 1):

Is the following what you want? i pick second column as you mentioned

```
Range(Cells(1,2), Cells(Total_Row, 2)).Select
```

Answer (score 1):

Range argument is string so you just need to concatenate it as string

```
Range("B1:B" & Total_Row).Select
```

Same with below line

```
RefersToR1C1:="=Database!R2C2:R" & Total_Row & "C2"
```